# Razor (MVC): Seeing razor files as normal HTML files in Dreamweaver 5.5 doesn't work

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, dreamweaver

.CSHTML files doesn't show the SPLIT / Design tabs in DW 5.5

I followed a tutorial of how to add a file extension to DW 5.5 to allow me to open it and it treats it as HTML but it isn't functioning.

Here is the line I changed. notice the addtional of cshtml

```
<documenttype id="HTML" internaltype="HTML" winfileextension="html,htm,shtml,shtm,stm,tpl,lasso,xhtml,cshtml"
```

The file is stored here:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Dreamweaver
>   CS5.5\configuration\DocumentTypes

What am I doing wrong?

My file type is basically a HTML file type with Divs etc etc but has some custom .NET code which its fine to treat as TEXT.

I open the file in Dreamweaver and it only shows the code tab, the DESIGN or SPLIT are still disabled.

And there is no color coding on, for example,  a div tag...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a read here about adding file extensions:
http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/164/tn_16410.html

In particular make sure you edit the copy in the user configuration folder, not the one in the application folder. If there isn't a copy in the user folder, create a copy in the appropriate location. I just followed those directions adding a CSHTML file extension to the document types and extensions file, and once Dreamweaver is restarted, a .cshtml file opened with the ability to view in design view.

Comment: Hallelujah! That was it. I was tired of editing the one in the Program Files folder. The right answer was on the Roaming!!! Thanks a million!! Using Adobe Dreamweaver CC.